# Autoit Code for File Upload not working in selenium.Windows disappears after entering the path

Tags: eclipse, selenium, autoit

I am facing a weird issue while running the Autoit code in  eclipse.

I created an exe file after compiling the below code to upload a text file in a windows pop up

If I manually run this exe file in command prompt with the window screen active
the file got uploaded to application successfully

The same exe code if I run through eclipse I can see that the button is pressed and window disappears(and no files are uploaded)

I tried by changing the Line 4 to send("{ENTER}") still no luck

```
1.WinWaitActive("Open") //Open is the  window name 
2.Send("C:\Users\AB\Desktop\sampleupload.txt",@SW_SHOWNORMAL) //this works in eclipse
3.WinWaitActive("Open")//this works
4.ControlClick("Open","","Button1") //Button clicked correctly

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filesend.exe")//code used in eclipse to run the autoit exe file
```

The file should get uploaded once the exe file is executed, but the window disappears and no file got uploaded.The issue is occurring only running through eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try run your `filesend.exe` using elevated privilege (e.g. Admin)

```
Runtime.exec("runas /user:adminUser filesend.exe");
```

Comment: I found out that the button is clicking .But now the issue is the document is not uploaded only through eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion, don't use exe from autoit. you can use autoit libraries using java or python.

Below is example of java with autoit:

```
File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.15-M4-x64.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
String notepad = "Untitled - Notepad";
String testString = "this is a test.";
x.run("notepad.exe");
x.winActivate(notepad);
x.winWaitActive(notepad);
x.send(testString);
Assert.assertTrue(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
x.winClose(notepad, testString);
x.winWaitActive("Notepad");
x.send("{ALT}n");
Assert.assertFalse(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
```

For setup you can refer following link:

https://www.joecolantonio.com/selenium-autoit/

If you want to use python with autoit and selenium you can implement very easily which I have written in below blog:

http://jbanshpal.blogspot.com/2018/02/first-basic-setup-and-example.html

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have used the same type of code in Autoit. There is some issue with the browser or the trigger which is blocking the file to upload.I couldn't figure out.

Comment: This is the code I used                                                                                       
  `File file =new File(base_dir+"\\src\\AutoIt\\lib\\jacob-1.18-x64.dll");`  
    
  `System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());`
  `AutoItX x=new AutoItX();`
  `x.sleep(2000);`                                                             
  `x.winWaitActive("Open");`                   
  `x.send("C:\\Users\\Apzal\\sampleupload.txt");`                             
  `x.sleep(3000);`
  `x.send("{ENTER}",false);`